# Pet not eating and lost weight

Tags: cats, eating

My cat just recently moved from being an out-door cat and living in a house to being an in-door cat in a apartment, he hasn't been eating from what I've seen although he does drink water. He hides all day when usually he likes to be out on the couch and hang with me. He also isn't meowing as much as he used to as he was a talker.

Should I take him to the vet or do you think its stress. He has lost weight I can feel his spine now which I never did before.

Comment: If it is more then 24 hours go to the vet.  Voting to close as a duplicate as we already have good answers about this question/